# Bubble sort in functional style Java 8

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, functional-programming, bubble-sort

How would you implement the following Bubble Sort algorithm in a functional (Java 8) way?

```java
public static final <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> imperativeBubbleSort(List<T> list) {
    int len = list == null ? 0 : list.size();
    for (int j = len - 1; j > 0; j--) {
        for (int k = 0; k < j; k++) {
            if (list.get(k + 1).compareTo(list.get(k)) < 0) {
                list.add(k, list.remove(k + 1));
            }
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: Bubble sort is a poor fit for functional programming in general. Merge sorts of lists and heap sorts are more natural in that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Algorithm with *two nested loops*: [Bubble sort with step-by-step output](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66959070/15553668)</sub>

---

#### Bubble sort with step-by-step output Java 8

You can replace *two nested loops* with *two nested streams*. The inner stream *passes* through the list, compares adjacent elements and returns the count of *swaps*. And the outer stream repeats *passes* until there is nothing left to *swap* in the inner stream.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
    Collections.addAll(list, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1);
    bubbleSort8(list);
}
```

```java
public static void bubbleSort8(List<Integer> list) {
    // counters: 0-passes, 1-swaps
    int[] counter = new int[2];
    IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 1)
        // output the beginning of the pass and increase the counter of passes
        .peek(i -> System.out.print((i==0?"<pre>":"<br>")+"Pass: "+counter[0]++))
        // repeat the passes through the list until
        // all the elements are in the correct order
        .anyMatch(i -> IntStream
            // pass through the list and
            // compare adjacent elements
            .range(0, list.size() - 1)
            // if this element is greater than the next one
            .filter(j -> list.get(j) > list.get(j + 1))
            // then swap them
            .peek(j -> Collections.swap(list, j, j + 1))
            // output the list and increase the counter of swaps
            .peek(j -> System.out.print(outputSwapped8(list,j,j+1,counter[1]++)))
            // if there are no swapped elements at the
            // current pass, then this is the last pass
            .count() == 0);
    // output total
    System.out.print("<br>Total: Passes=" + counter[0]);
    System.out.println(", swaps=" + counter[1] + "</pre>");
}
```

```java
static String outputSwapped8(List<Integer> list, int e1, int e2, int counter) {
    return IntStream.range(0, list.size())
            .mapToObj(i -> i == e1 || i == e2 ?
                    // swapped elements are in bold
                    "<b>" + list.get(i) + "</b>" :
                    // other elements
                    "" + list.get(i))
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" ", "<br>", " | " + counter));
}
```

Output:

```
Pass: 0
9 10 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 | 0
9 8 10 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 | 1
9 8 7 10 6 5 4 3 2 1 | 2
9 8 7 6 10 5 4 3 2 1 | 3
9 8 7 6 5 10 4 3 2 1 | 4
9 8 7 6 5 4 10 3 2 1 | 5
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 10 2 1 | 6
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 10 1 | 7
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 10 | 8
Pass: 1
8 9 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 10 | 9
8 7 9 6 5 4 3 2 1 10 | 10
8 7 6 9 5 4 3 2 1 10 | 11
8 7 6 5 9 4 3 2 1 10 | 12
8 7 6 5 4 9 3 2 1 10 | 13
8 7 6 5 4 3 9 2 1 10 | 14
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 9 1 10 | 15
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 9 10 | 16
Pass: 2
7 8 6 5 4 3 2 1 9 10 | 17
7 6 8 5 4 3 2 1 9 10 | 18
7 6 5 8 4 3 2 1 9 10 | 19
7 6 5 4 8 3 2 1 9 10 | 20
7 6 5 4 3 8 2 1 9 10 | 21
7 6 5 4 3 2 8 1 9 10 | 22
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 8 9 10 | 23
Pass: 3
6 7 5 4 3 2 1 8 9 10 | 24
6 5 7 4 3 2 1 8 9 10 | 25
6 5 4 7 3 2 1 8 9 10 | 26
6 5 4 3 7 2 1 8 9 10 | 27
6 5 4 3 2 7 1 8 9 10 | 28
6 5 4 3 2 1 7 8 9 10 | 29
Pass: 4
5 6 4 3 2 1 7 8 9 10 | 30
5 4 6 3 2 1 7 8 9 10 | 31
5 4 3 6 2 1 7 8 9 10 | 32
5 4 3 2 6 1 7 8 9 10 | 33
5 4 3 2 1 6 7 8 9 10 | 34
Pass: 5
4 5 3 2 1 6 7 8 9 10 | 35
4 3 5 2 1 6 7 8 9 10 | 36
4 3 2 5 1 6 7 8 9 10 | 37
4 3 2 1 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 38
Pass: 6
3 4 2 1 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 39
3 2 4 1 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 40
3 2 1 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 41
Pass: 7
2 3 1 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 42
2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 43
Pass: 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 44
Pass: 9
Total: Passes=10, swaps=45
```

---

<sup>See also: [Bubble sort algorithm for a linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66977868/15553668)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

It would depend on what you mean by functional. If you mean just passing around functions as first class objects, then you should change your method signature to be:

```
public static final <T> List<T> imperativeBubbleSort(List<T> list, Comparator<T> comparisonFunction)
```

This way the comparison logic can be supplied as an argument.

If you mean going fully functional and not at all procedural, then I would call it an anti-pattern. Despite what you might hear, Java 8 does not fully support functional programming. A key feature that it is missing is tail-call optimization. Without it, the sort of loop-less programming that defines functional programming is likely to crash your JVM for relatively small values.

More information about tail call optimizations and the JVM can be found here: http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/tail-call-optimization-and-java/240167044

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Java 8 will provide much help in this case to write bubble sort in a functional style.

For example this implementation [implementation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Sorting/Bubble_sort#Haskell) of Bubble sort in Haskell can be simulated in Java as follows. It's more functional as it uses recursion instead of iteration, but still Java 8 lacks
features such as pattern matching, list concatenation, etc to express the algorithms in a more functional style.

```
public static final <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> functionalBubbleSort(List<T> list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        list = onePassSort(list);
    }
    return list;
}

public static final <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> onePassSort(List<T> list) {
    if (list.size() == 0 || list.size() == 1) { 
        return list;
    } else {
        T first = list.get(0);
        T second = list.get(1);
        if (first.compareTo(second) < 0) {
            return merge(first, onePassSort(list.subList(1, list.size())));
        } else {
            return merge(second, onePassSort(merge(first, list.subList(2, list.size()))));
        }
    }
}

public static <T> List<T> merge(T head, List<T> tail) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>();
    result.add(head);
    result.addAll(tail);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shortest way I could think of is following.  Where listForBubbleSort is input, and bubbleSorted is the output.

```java
List<Integer> listForBubbleSort = Arrays.asList(5, 4, 3, 7, 6, 9, 11, 10, 21);

final List<Integer> copiedList = new ArrayList<>(listForBubbleSort);
copiedList.add(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

final List<Integer> bubbleSorted = new ArrayList<>();

copiedList.stream().reduce((c, e) -> {
    if (c < e) {
        bubbleSorted.add(c);
        return e;
    } else {
        bubbleSorted.add(e);
        return c;
    }
});

System.out.println(bubbleSorted); // [4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 21]
```

I still feel that, if we could create a custom collector and just pass the collector to the collect of stream that would be great. Like we pass `collect(toList())` to the stream. But still learning Java 8, so need more time to create the same.
If anyone has already created a custom collector for the same please share.

Comment: Yeah, in fact I'm finding out that trying to solve this algorithm using functional is against functional programming concepts.

Comment: The solution is using Java8 features, but it is not functional because you have mutable state (you're adding elements to the mutable list).

Answer (score 0):

I got a plausible approach:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> declarativeBubbleSort(final List<T> list) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(list);
    int len = result.size();
    Function<Function<Object, Object>, IntConsumer> consumer =
            recur -> length -> IntStream.range(0, length)
                    .filter(i -> IntStream.range(0, len - i - 1)
                            .filter(j -> result.get(j + 1).compareTo(result.get(j)) < 0)
                            .mapToObj(j -> {
                                T swap = result.remove(j + 1);
                                result.add(j, swap);
                                return swap;
                            }).count() > 0)
                    .max().ifPresent(IntConsumer.class.cast(recur.apply(Function.class.cast(recur))));
    consumer.apply(Function.class.cast(consumer)).accept(len);
    return result;
}
```

I know I'm still being a bit imperative, but for this kind of sort, I find it hard to do it completely declarative in Java and not to penalize performance.

If you want to be parallel, then:

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static final <T extends Comparable<T>> List<T> declarativeParallelBubbleSort(final List<T> list) {
    List<T> result = new ArrayList<>(list);
    int len = result.size();
    Function<Function<Object, Object>, IntConsumer> consumer =
            recur -> length -> IntStream.range(0, length)
                    .filter(i -> IntStream.range(0, len - i - 1)
                            .filter(j -> result.get(j + 1).compareTo(result.get(j)) < 0)
                            .parallel()
                            .mapToObj(j -> {
                                synchronized (result) {
                                    T swap = result.remove(j + 1);
                                    result.add(j, swap);
                                    return swap;
                                }
                            }).count() > 0)
                    .max().ifPresent(IntConsumer.class.cast(recur.apply(Function.class.cast(recur))));
    consumer.apply(Function.class.cast(consumer)).accept(len);
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version using Java 8 api:

```java
public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] array) {
    BiConsumer<int[], Integer> swapValueIf = (a, j) -> {
        if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
            int temp = a[j];
            array[j] = a[j + 1];
            array[j + 1] = temp;
        }
    };

    IntStream.range(0, array.length - 1)
            .forEach(i -> IntStream.range(0, array.length - 1)
                    .forEach(j -> swapValueIf.accept(array, j)));
    return array;
}
```