# Bubble sort with output

Tags: java, arrays, counter, swap, bubble-sort

So I have edited it some and am getting almost exactly what I want. The only problem I am having now is that I am getting a line of output that I don't want. I feel like the fix here is simple but my brain is fried right now.

```java
static void bubbleSort(int[] myArray) {
    int n = myArray.length;
    int temp = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int k;
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            System.out.print(myArray[k] + "|");
        }
        System.out.println(" Num swaps: " + counter);
        for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
            if (myArray[j - 1] > myArray[j]) {
                //swap elements
                temp = myArray[j - 1];
                myArray[j - 1] = myArray[j];
                myArray[j] = temp;
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] myArray = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.print("Enter slot " + i + ": ");
        myArray[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }
    bubbleSort(myArray);
}
```

Here is an example of what I get:

```
Enter slot 0: 10
Enter slot 1: 9
Enter slot 2: 8
Enter slot 3: 7
Enter slot 4: 6
Enter slot 5: 5
Enter slot 6: 4
Enter slot 7: 3
Enter slot 8: 2
Enter slot 9: 1
10|9|8|7|6|5|4|3|2|1| Num swaps: 0
9|8|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|10| Num swaps: 9
8|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|9|10| Num swaps: 17
7|6|5|4|3|2|1|8|9|10| Num swaps: 24
6|5|4|3|2|1|7|8|9|10| Num swaps: 30
5|4|3|2|1|6|7|8|9|10| Num swaps: 35
4|3|2|1|5|6|7|8|9|10| Num swaps: 39
3|2|1|4|5|6|7|8|9|10| Num swaps: 42
2|1|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10| Num swaps: 44
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10| Num swaps: 45
```

That first line of output where it just repeats what the user input and says 0 swaps. I don't want that.

Answer (score 1):

Just changed the position of the for loops. Hope this is the output you actually want :).

```java
static void bubbleSort(int[] myArray) {
    int n = myArray.length;
    int temp = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < (n - i); j++) {
            if (myArray[j - 1] > myArray[j]) {
                // swap elements
                temp = myArray[j - 1];
                myArray[j - 1] = myArray[j];
                myArray[j] = temp;
                counter++;
            }
        }
        int k;
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {
            System.out.print(myArray[k] + "|");
        }
        System.out.println(" Num swaps: " + counter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Algorithm with *two nested streams*: [Bubble sort with step-by-step output Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66978872/15553668)</sub>

---

#### Bubble sort with step-by-step output

The outer *do-while-loop* repeats until the array is sorted, and the inner *for-loop* passes through the array, swapping the unordered adjacent elements. The output is the *swapped* elements in the inner loop, grouped by *passes* in the outer loop.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
    bubbleSort(arr);
}
```

```java
public static void bubbleSort(int[] arr) {
    // counters
    int passes = 0, swaps = 0;
    // marker
    boolean swapped;
    // repeat the passes through the array until
    // all the elements are in the correct order
    do {
        // output the beginning of the pass and increase the counter of passes
        System.out.print((passes == 0 ? "<pre>" : "<br>") + "Pass: " + passes++);
        swapped = false;
        // pass through the array and
        // compare adjacent elements
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            // if this element is greater than
            // the next one, then swap them
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = temp;
                swapped = true;
                // output the array and increase the counter of swaps
                System.out.print(outputSwapped(arr, i, i + 1, swaps++));
            }
        }
        // if there are no swapped elements at the
        // current pass, then this is the last pass
    } while (swapped);
    // output total
    System.out.print("<br>Total: Passes=" + passes);
    System.out.println(", swaps=" + swaps + "</pre>");
}
```

```java
static String outputSwapped(int[] arr, int e1, int e2, int counter) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<br>");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (i == e1 || i == e2) {
            // swapped elements are in bold
            sb.append("<b>").append(arr[i]).append("</b>");
        } else {
            // other elements
            sb.append(arr[i]);
        }
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    return sb.append("| ").append(counter).toString();
}
```

Output:

```
Pass: 0
9 10 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 | 0
9 8 10 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 | 1
9 8 7 10 6 5 4 3 2 1 | 2
9 8 7 6 10 5 4 3 2 1 | 3
9 8 7 6 5 10 4 3 2 1 | 4
9 8 7 6 5 4 10 3 2 1 | 5
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 10 2 1 | 6
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 10 1 | 7
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 10 | 8
Pass: 1
8 9 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 10 | 9
8 7 9 6 5 4 3 2 1 10 | 10
8 7 6 9 5 4 3 2 1 10 | 11
8 7 6 5 9 4 3 2 1 10 | 12
8 7 6 5 4 9 3 2 1 10 | 13
8 7 6 5 4 3 9 2 1 10 | 14
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 9 1 10 | 15
8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 9 10 | 16
Pass: 2
7 8 6 5 4 3 2 1 9 10 | 17
7 6 8 5 4 3 2 1 9 10 | 18
7 6 5 8 4 3 2 1 9 10 | 19
7 6 5 4 8 3 2 1 9 10 | 20
7 6 5 4 3 8 2 1 9 10 | 21
7 6 5 4 3 2 8 1 9 10 | 22
7 6 5 4 3 2 1 8 9 10 | 23
Pass: 3
6 7 5 4 3 2 1 8 9 10 | 24
6 5 7 4 3 2 1 8 9 10 | 25
6 5 4 7 3 2 1 8 9 10 | 26
6 5 4 3 7 2 1 8 9 10 | 27
6 5 4 3 2 7 1 8 9 10 | 28
6 5 4 3 2 1 7 8 9 10 | 29
Pass: 4
5 6 4 3 2 1 7 8 9 10 | 30
5 4 6 3 2 1 7 8 9 10 | 31
5 4 3 6 2 1 7 8 9 10 | 32
5 4 3 2 6 1 7 8 9 10 | 33
5 4 3 2 1 6 7 8 9 10 | 34
Pass: 5
4 5 3 2 1 6 7 8 9 10 | 35
4 3 5 2 1 6 7 8 9 10 | 36
4 3 2 5 1 6 7 8 9 10 | 37
4 3 2 1 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 38
Pass: 6
3 4 2 1 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 39
3 2 4 1 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 40
3 2 1 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 41
Pass: 7
2 3 1 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 42
2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 43
Pass: 8
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 | 44
Pass: 9
Total: Passes=10, swaps=45
```

---

<sup>See also: [Bubble sort output is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66970037/15553668)</sup>