# Sort in-place; without dynamically allocate new memory (using LinkedList)

Tags: sorting, data-structures, linked-list

What is in-Place Sorting?

I wanted to sort a linked list (sort must be in-place), and not allowed to use any new memory.

How can we sort without using a temporary Node?

Thanks,
Isa

Comment: You might find the answers at this question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168164/sorting-linked-lists-in-c

Comment: Please tell us what language this is.

Comment: Meditate over [Insertion Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) for example.

Comment: in-Place sort is sort process do not allocating extra memory for sort place and does the process by replacing (e.g. bubble sort). You can easily perform link list in-place sort by delete/insert operation in on the list.